# When writing .wav file from AudioInputStream, Windows Media Player can't play it

Tags: java, audio, wav, windows-media-player

I'm trying to write a file from an AudioInputStream. The stream can read the original file just fine (as far as I can tell). But when it tries to write, it writes what should be a 15 KB file in 44 bytes. Windows Media Player gives the error "either the file type is unsupported, or WMP doesn't recognize the codec used to convert the file."

I got most of this code from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html. I've looked all over StackOverflow but nothing seemed to pertain to this problem.

I've tried getting the format of the AudioInputStream and it's definitely a .wav. As far as I can tell, a codec is software that converts analog to digital data, and both the wav file and the AudioInputStream are digital already.

EDIT: It looks like the stream is writing the WAVE file header to my new file, but nothing else. That's where my 44 byte file is coming from.

Here's the code. I think the problem is in writeFile() but I included the rest just in case:

```
public static void getFile()
{
    try
    {
    File test = new File("C:\\Users\\Audrey\\Steganography\\correctamundo.wav"); //file to be written from
    AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(test);
    AudioFileFormat format = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(test);
    int bytesPerFrame = stream.getFormat().getFrameSize();
    byte[] b = new byte[30000]; //array of arbitrary size to hold the bytes in stream

    if (bytesPerFrame == AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED) //not sure why this is necessary
       {
           bytesPerFrame = 1;
       } 
    int i = 0;

    while(stream.available() > 0)
    {
        byte currentByte = (byte)stream.read();
        b[i] = currentByte; //read bytes to array
        System.out.println(b[i] + "   " +(i+1)); //test statement
        i++;
    }

    writeFile(format, stream);

    } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void writeFile (AudioFileFormat format, AudioInputStream stream) //format and stream created in getFile() under the same names
{
    try
     {
         File fileOut = new File("C:\\Users\\Audrey\\Steganography\\testFile2.wav"); 
         AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = format.getType(); //type of file the AudioInputStream can write to, since format refers to stream

         if (AudioSystem.isFileTypeSupported(fileType, stream)) 
         {
             AudioSystem.write(stream, fileType, fileOut);
             System.out.println(stream.getFrameLength()); //test statement
         }
         System.out.println(fileType); //test statement
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you rewind the stream before the call to writeFile?

Comment: @jaket Do you mean use stream.close()? I tried, and it didn't change anything. When I try stream.reset() it tells me mark/reset is not supported, which I've heard you can fix by making stream into a BufferedInputStream, but is there an easier way? I can't get a format from a BufferedInputStream.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an exact answer for you since I'm not a Java programmer. I just know that typically a stream has notion of a read pointer that advances as you read from it. It looks to me that you've read to the end of the stream before the call to writeFile and thus there would be nothing remaining to write. Also, I would guess that the 44 bytes are the beginning of the WAVE file format up to but not including the actual data.

Comment: ....that worked. Moving the writeFile() declaration to inside the while loop, that is. @jaket; you have just saved my grade and my science fair presentation, thank you.